# Quoting public domain text

Tags: support, copyright

I did quite a bit of quoting in this question: [What is unique about Christianity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/what-is-unique-about-christianity/4008#4008)  which raised eyebrows about whether I was breaking some copyright laws by doing so.

I know that it is completely legal for the majority of the English speaking nations to access what is public domain in the United States, but does it fit with the multi-national nature of this network of sites to use public domain works.

I strongly wanted to quote the source in it's entirety to get the point across, I think it's tragic how badly out of context people take Chesterton and I don't think he'd appreciate anything less.

Comment: I don't quite understand the `multi-national nature` point. If you're referring to different legislations of users, I wouldn't mind. We can't possibly know every legislation. We probably already have content that's illegal in some of the strictest Islamic countries.

Answer (score 6):

I see no problem in quoting as much as is necessary, whenever copyright allows that. The SE servers [are located in the United States](http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=christianity.stackexchange.com), so the US copyright law applies.

It might be wise to note the license used in cases like this. I've been doing that for images, as they mostly could not be legally embedded unless license specifically allows that.